# CORS Error that is not fixed with usual solution

Tags: c#, angular, wcf, cors

I have a C# .NET (v4.8) WCF service that is being accessed by an Angular 14 site.  I have set them up as separate websites on my local machine (Angular site is localhost, WCF service is localhost:4506).

I'm getting a CORS error when the Angular site tries to access the services on the WCF site.  Google foo says that to correct the problem, I have to add the following to the Gobal.aspx.cs file for my service:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
if(HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS") {
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
   }
}
```

I've added that, published the new code, and I'm still getting the CORS error.

I've also tried adding this to the web.config:

```
<httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"/>
   </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

No success with this or a couple of other variations of this.

What else can I try?

Comment: you may not be able to set allow-origin to a wildcard.  (are you sending credentials/cookies in the request?)  Try setting specifc domain, localhost: port.  If this doesn't help, include the full CORS error you are receiving.

Comment: Looks like that is it browsermator!  I know I read a couple of places that said you could use the wild card but maybe something has been updated since those posts.  Thanks a bunch!!